# VB.net Dataset display different column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, datasource

I am sure this has to a comon thing I just can't find it. I am making a combobox from my data source.

Basically, This is a projects form and the user needs to select the the primary contact which is contrained by the customer id (GETbyCustomerID) set in another field. I have it working... mostly except the combobox only displays the contact ID which is completely useless to the user. I need to know how to display the First and Last name (both are seperate columns in the table). Any help? I am just using the designer.

Answer (score 1):

The ComboBox will have properties for [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) you can set appropriately.

The easiest way to use two columns as the DisplayMember is to return them as one in your query and use that value (in your case - `FirstName + LastName as FullName`).